# Change column name on model creating with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, propertyinfo

I'm looking for any solution to change the column names during building the database using Entity Framework.

I have a sample code below:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<SysUser>().Property(p => p.Enable).HasColumnName("newColumnName");
}
```

This works, but I want to automate this action of changing the column names, i.e. get some part of entities, and change the column name.

To do this, I wrote the code below, but I'm stuck. To get all entities, I used `Types`, which can't be converted into `EntityTypeConfiguration<>`.

```
// This gets all of defined DbSet<> in database contexts
var contextProp = this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => (p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().Count() == 1)).ToList();

foreach (PropertyInfo entity in contextProp )
{
   // get generic type from DbSet
   Type entityType = entity.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
   foreach (PropertyInfo entityProp in entityType.GetProperties())
   {
      // I'm stuck here
      // entityType = SysUser
      // entityProp = Enable
   }
}
```

Why am I doing this? Beceuse in one class I have another class.
Entity Framework renders fields adding the method name at the end of column name.

For example:

```
public class x
{
   public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class y
{
   public x { get; set; }
}

// ... some database context
DbSet<y> y { get; set; }
```

The database is created with a table named `y` with a column named `x_Value`.

I can't use `ColumnAttribute`, because this option sets the same column name for all classes. Name of columns should be the same as property `x { get; set; }`.

Comment: Have you considered the fact that you cannot change column name on runtime?

Comment: Considering your example of classes `y` and `x`, could you edit your question and add an example of what do you expect the newly created `y` table to be?

Comment: What exactly is the problem, and what are you trying to achieve?